# Which one have better performance : Derived Tables or Temporary Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql

Sometimes we can write a query with both derived table and temporary table. my question is that which one is better? why?

Comment: what about @tableVariables ;-)

Comment: @KM: You are playing with the terrible forces here.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Derived table is a logical construct.

It may be stored in the `tempdb`, built at runtime by reevaluating the underlying statement each time it is accessed, or even optimized out at all.

Temporary table is a physical construct. It is a table in `tempdb` that is created and populated with the values.

Which one is better depends on the query they are used in, the statement that is used to derive a table, and many other factors.

For instance, `CTE` (common table expressions) in `SQL Server` can (and most probably will) be reevaluated each time they are used. This query:

```
WITH    q (uuid) AS
        (
        SELECT  NEWID()
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    q
UNION ALL
SELECT  *
FROM    q
```

will *most probably* yield two different `NEWID()`'s.

In this case, a temporary table should be used since it guarantees that its values persist.

On the other hand, this query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
        SELECT  *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
        FROM    master
        ) q
WHERE   rn BETWEEN 80 AND 100
```

is better with a derived table, because using a temporary table will require fetching all values from `master`, while this solution will just scan the first `100` records using the index on `id`.

Comment: when is better for using Derived Tables? in simple queries?

Comment: why did you use 'most probably' here - "will most probably yield two different NEWID()'s." ?

Comment: @thewpfguy: because it's not a guaranteed behaviour.

Comment: @Quassnoi Temporary table will require fetching all values from tempdb and not masterdb.

Comment: @Sam: what's masterdb?

Answer (score 11):

It depends on the circumstances.

Advantages of derived tables:

1. A derived table is part of a larger, single query, and will be optimized in the context of the rest of the query. This can be an advantage, if the query optimization helps performance (it usually does, with some exceptions). Example: if you populate a temp table, then consume the results in a second query, you are in effect tying the database engine to one execution method (run the first query in its entirety, save the whole result, run the second query) where with a derived table the optimizer might be able to find a faster execution method or access path.
2. A derived table only "exists" in terms of the query execution plan - it's purely a logical construct. There really is no table.

Advantages of temp tables

1. The table "exists" - that is, it's materialized as a table, at least in memory, which contains the result set and can be reused.
2. In some cases, performance can be improved or blocking reduced when you have to perform some elaborate transformation on the data - for example, if you want to fetch a 'snapshot' set of rows out of a base table that is busy, and then do some complicated calculation on that set, there can be less contention if you get the rows out of the base table and unlock it as quickly as possible, then do the work independently. In some cases the overhead of a real temp table is small relative to the advantage in concurrency.

Answer (score 5):

I want to add an anecdote here as it leads me to advise the opposite of the accepted answer.  I agree with the thinking presented in the accepted answer but it is mostly theoretical.  My experience has lead me to recommend temp tables over derived tables, common table expressions and table value functions.  We used derived tables and common table expressions extensively with much success based on thoughts consistent with the accepted answer until we started dealing with larger result sets and/or more complex queries.  Then we found that the optimizer did not optimize well with the derived table or CTE.

I looked at an example today that ran for 10:15.  I inserted the results from the derived table into a temp table and joined the temp table in the main query and the total time dropped to 0:03.  Usually when we see a big performance problem we can quickly address it this way.  For this reason I recommend temp tables unless your query is relatively simple and you are certain it will not be processing large data sets.

Answer (score 0):

The big difference is that you can put constraints including a primary key on a temporary table. For big (I mean millions of records) sometime you can get better performance with temporary.  I have the key query that needs 5 joins (each joins happens to be similar).  Performance was OK with 2 joins and then on the third performance went bad and query plan went crazy.  Even with hints I could not correct the query plan.  Tried restructuring the joins as derived tables and still same performance issues.  With with temporary tables can create a primary key (then when I populate first sort on PK).   When SQL could join the 5 tables and use the PK performance went from minutes to seconds.   I wish SQL would support constraints on derived tables and CTE (even if only a PK).