# When is it not appropriate to use Derived tables?

Tags: sql, derived-table

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326395/which-one-have-better-performance-derived-tables-or-temporary-tables) details some benefits in performance regarding Derived vs. Temporary tables.

Other than performance, what situations exist for which a Derived table would not be appropriate.

One answer per post with an example would be helpful.

Comment: That [question is tagged for SQL Server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326395/which-one-have-better-performance-derived-tables-or-temporary-tables), so the info should be considered specific to it and not for all databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would prefer to do a **self-join** on a temporary table than a derived table.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS SELECT ...;

SELECT ... FROM foo f1 JOIN foo f2 ON ...conditions...;
```

Versus using a derived table, where you have to write the whole query twice:

```
SELECT ... 
FROM (SELECT ...)
JOIN (SELECT ...) ON ...conditions...;
```

But another solution is to use *common table expressions* which are slightly different from derived tables:

```
WITH foo AS (SELECT ...)
SELECT ... FROM foo f1 JOIN foo f2 ON ...conditions...;
```

Provided you use a brand of database that supports this syntax (Microsoft, Oracle, IBM, PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 1):

Scope might be one.  I think temp tables can be made accessible to other transactions / processes, etc.  Derived tables are limited to the block in which they are declared.

Answer (score 1):

If you have to access the data in the temporary table in **multiple queries** it might be less costly to avoid generating the temp data repeatedly:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE foo AS SELECT ...;

SELECT ... FROM foo WHERE ...conditions...;

-- sometime later

SELECT ... FROM foo WHERE ...different conditions...;
```